# Inserting values into table from textboxes & from another table's foreign key C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Im trying to insert into a table values from textboxes AND to retrieve a foreign key id from another table and insert that also.

So I have a users table which contains UserId and I want this inserted into a nutrition diary which includes all the data that comes from textboxes(ie Weight, Height, Date etc)

I am retrieving the MemberId by using a session to track the username(lblRegistered)
Here is my code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("path for my connection");
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select COUNT(*)FROM Members where Username='" + lblRegistered.Text + "'", con);

con.Close();

con.Open();

cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Nutrition(Weight, Height, Bmi, Date, WaterIntake, CalorieIntake, MemberId) values ('" + txtWeight.Text + "','" + txtHeight.Text + "','" + txtBmi.Text + "','" + txtDate.Text + "','" + txtWater.Text + "','" + txtCalorie.Text + "', Select Users.UserId From Users where (Users.Username= '" + lblRegistered.Text + "'))";

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Clone();
con.Close();
Response.Redirect("Success.aspx");
```

The error is close to **Select** Users part.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you are missing one space between count and from

Comment: @Selman22 That is still valid SQL.  I believe the problem comes from trying to do an `INSERT` and a `SELECT` in one command.  You should do the `SELECT` first, store that in a variable, and pass it into the `INSERT`.

Comment: Thanks guys. I am new to this so i'm not sure how I would go about that. Would that include using an execute scalar?
Something along the lines of:
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select MemberId FROM Members where Username='" + lblRegistered.Text + "'", con);

int UserId;
            UserId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd2.ExecuteScalar());

And then have 'UserId' in the values?

Comment: That would be correct.  You might want to check out the answer that Richard Seal has though.  He makes a good point about SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing would be to read up on parameterized SQL queries. The code you have there is completely open to SQL injection attacks.

This is a good resource for that: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html

Then for the problem you would be better off using a Stored Procedure to do the work. Something along the lines of :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Nutrition_Insert
    @weight varchar(10),
    @height varchar(10),
    @bmi varchar(10),
    @date varchar(10),
    @username varchar(10),
    //etc for your fields
AS BEGIN

    DECLARE @memberId varchar(10)
    SELECT @memberId = UserId From Users where Username = @username

    INSERT INTO Nutrition(Weight, Height, Bmi, Date, WaterIntake, CalorieIntake, MemberId) 
    values (@weight, @height, @bmi, ....., @memberId)

END
```

Note - I've made some assumptions there as I don't know your data types, they all look like strings, but not knowing the size of the varchar used,  I picked an arbitary value. Replace the (10) with the actual field size.

If you must use embedded SQL - then this is how you parameterize it. I've also fixed the insert statement to pull the MemberId from the Members table as part of the insert.

```
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (
                var cmd = new SqlCommand(
                    "INSERT INTO Nutrition(...fields...) SELECT @Weight, @Height, @Bmi,...., Members.MemberId FROM Members WHERE Members.Username = @Username", conn)
                )
            {

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Weight", txtWeight.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Height", txtHeight.Text);
                ...
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", lblRegistered.Text);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
```

You'll notice the `using` statements too. This will make sure your connection are disposed of cleanly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I am new to this c# and.Would using Parameters also be an option?
The below code is coming up with errors but I think I may not be too far away?

                  cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Nutrition(Weight, Height, Bmi, Date, MemberId) values ('" + txtWeight.Text + "','" + txtHeight.Text + "','" + txtBmi.Text + "','" + txtDate.Text + '", @MemberId)";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemberId","Select Members.MemberId From Members where Members.Username= '" + lblRegistered.Text + "');

Can you use parameters and then use a SQL statement to retrieve the MemberId?

Comment: Edited my answer to give an embedded SQL example

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Richard..that worked very well on the problem.
I am just trying to do the same technique on a different page but this time it will have 2 where clauses

```
  var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO AssignPlan(Reps, Sets, WeightOrTime, Date, MemberId, ExerciseId) Select @Reps, @Sets,@WeightOrTime,@Date, Members.MemberId From Members Where Members.Username=@name,ExerciseDisplay.ExerciseId From ExerciseDisplay Where ExerciseDisplay.ExerciseName=@Exercise", conn)
```

It's showing up an error from the syntax. Can this be achieved?

Comment: This would be more appropriate as a comment to Richard's answer. Also, this is exactly the same problem - see if you can figure out how to change the code he already wrote for you. Or if you just need help figuring out your syntax error, ask a new question - or better yet, find a SQL validator.

Comment: You're getting into more complicated SQL there, I'm sure I could re-write that to do what you want, but I think you really need to be looking at using a Stored Procedure to do it, the more complicated your embedded SQL gets, the harder it will be to maintain.